# Why is Cauchy-Riemann equation not sufficient for differentiablity

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

In my undergraduate complex analysis textbook, it claims that Cauchy Riemann equations is not a sufficient condition for the existence of derivative. Intuitively, I do not understand why this is true, as if you satisfied
$$u_x=v_y$$
$$u_y=-v_x$$

it implies that both
$$f_x \;\; and\;\; f_y$$ exist and therefore $f$ should be differentiable

Any hint would be much appreciated

Comment: There are functions where $f_x$ and $f_y$ both exist, but $f$ itself is not continuous and so it is not differentiable. To get differentiability, you need the partials to be continuous.  See here: http://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Existence_of_partial_derivatives_not_implies_differentiable

Comment: if $f$ is differentiable in respect to $x$ and $y$ doesn't it imply continuous of $f$?

Comment: Nope, if $f$ itself is differentiable, then $f$ is continuous, but being differentiable in higher dimensions is different than having partial derivatives.

Comment: @xbd: Take $f$ to be a function that is one everywhere except on the $x,y$ axes where it takes the value zero. Clearly not continuous, but the partials exist.

Comment: @xbd a sufficient condition for $f$ to be differentiable is the existence and continuity of all partial derivatives (not continuity of $f$ itself).

Comment: Sorry to re-awaken an ancient thread haha but I was wondering, are the CRE a necessary condition for a function $f$ to be complex differentiable at a point $z_0$ (I agree it is not a sufficient condition)?

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x+iy) = \sqrt{|x||y|}$. The Cauchy Riemann equations are satisfied at $z=0$, but $f$ is not differentiable (in $\mathbb{C}$) at $z=0$.