# Relationship Between CR equations and Complex Differentiability

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Consider a complex function $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ where $u,v$ are real-valued functions.

In an attempt to better understand complex differentiation and the Cauchy-Riemann equations, I considered two questions.

> If $f$ is complex differentiable at a point $z_o$, do the Cauchy-Riemann equations have to hold?

Yes (although not really sure on reasoning).

> If the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold at $z_o$, does $f$ have to be complex differentiable there?

No, this not a sufficient condition. Further continuity conditions are required (e.g. partial derivatives are continuous at $z_0$).

Am I correct? Advice on these two questions would be really appreciated.

Comment: For the second see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/496068/why-is-cauchy-riemann-equation-not-sufficient-for-differentiablity?rq=1

Comment: Nice link, thanks for that. What about the first question?

Comment: the first one is a theorem in complex analysis. `If f is complex differentiable at a point z_0, then the Cauchy-Riemann equations hold.`